# How do I skip some optional arguments in Robot Framework?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, robotframework

My intend is to skip the **${num2}** and **${num4}** arguments.
But I got an error saying:

> Positional argument cannot be used after named arguments

I don't know why it considers the list as a positional argument, shouldn't it be a variable one?

```
*** Test Cases ***  
Test  
    @{daysOff}=    Create List    Tuesday    Friday  
    Keyword    30    num3=6    @{daysOff}  
  
*** Keywords ***  
Keyword  
    [Arguments]    ${num1}    ${num2}=5    ${num3}=10    ${num4}=15    @{list}  
    Log    ${num1}  
    Log    ${num2}  
    Log    ${num3}  
    Log    ${num4}  
    FOR    ${item}    IN   @{list}
        Log    ${item}
    END
```

Comment: Please accept the answers which works for you by clicking on hollow tick beside the answer. This is the way of appreciating the person who spent his valuable time to answer your question. It also helps and direct community members to the working answers.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve the

> Positional argument cannot be used after named arguments

error you should move the list argument before the named, positional arguments.
Note that you cannot move it before `${num1}` as that would give another error:

> Keyword 'Keyword' missing named-only argument 'num1'.

All in all:

```
*** Test Cases ***  
Test  
    @{daysOff}=    Create List    Tuesday    Friday  
    Keyword    30    @{daysOff}    num3=6
  
*** Keywords ***  
Keyword
    [Arguments]    ${num1}    @{list}    ${num2}=5    ${num3}=10    ${num4}=15    
    Log    ${num1}  
    Log    ${num2}  
    Log    ${num3}  
    Log    ${num4}  
    FOR    ${item}    IN   @{list}
        Log    ${item}
    END
```

Comment: Robot Framework uses three types of argument: Positional, Default and Variable. I want the list to be Variable.

Comment: @user2420374 I have updated my answer to align it with your updated question.